# remove and add class on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap Modal and I want the modal to have 750px width on large desktops. When I resize the window and make it smaller, the modal is no longer responsive, therefore I added a class to the modal and gave it 750px width and I delete this class when the window is smaller than 800. The problem is that once the class is deleted, it remains deleted, so how can I add again the class when the window is bigger than 800? So far I have this

```
function checkWidth() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
    $('div').removeClass('modal-width');
  }

}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: Are you aware of media queries?

Comment: can media queries delete and add a class? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `JavaScript` you could also do this with [`CSS media queries`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 800px){
  .modal{
      width: 750px;
   }
}
```

This rule only gets applied when the browsers width is 800px or more.

Comment: don't know why I didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

Using `@media` in css or by `javascript`.

There is code :

```
<body onresize="chClass();">
    <div id="div" class="modal-width">
    </div>
</body>

.modal-width
{
 background-color:blue;
    width:400px; height:400px;
    display:block;
}

function chClass() {
    var dd=document.getElementById('div');
    if(window.innerWidth<300) {
        dd.removeAttribute('class');
    } else {
        dd.setAttribute('class','modal-width');
    }
}
```

Look this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bqzs9br8/)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/f7ymgyL5/)**

If you are insistent on not using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), the following will work.

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 800)
        $('div').removeClass('modal-width');
    else
        $('div').addClass('modal-width');
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
        if ($(this).width() < 800) {
            $('body').addClass('modal-width')
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('modal-width')
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question properly but for responsive modals add "modal-wide" to the main modal div, and adjust the width in the CSS. In this example, I'm using 90%.
Since I'm using jQuery to set the max-height of the content area based on the browser dimensions, the modal will be only as tall as necessary, and will provide a scrollbar if needed.

And if you want to resize it just change the css parameters.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#normalModal" class="btn btn-default">Normal</a>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#tallModal" class="btn btn-primary">Wide, Tall Content</a>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#shortModal" class="btn btn-primary">Wide, Short Content</a>

<div id="normalModal" class="modal fade"></div>
<div id="tallModal" class="modal modal-wide fade"></div>
<div id="shortModal" class="modal modal-wide fade"></div>
```

**EXAMPLE :** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahajanankur/qghLrLjh/)

I hope this will work for you.